# What's the problem in this HTML for UIWebView on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am trying to run this html in UIWebView in iPhone. My requirement is that the font size should not change on rotation. And font should be Arial.

when i use css, 32px "font size constant on rotation" problem is solved, but Arial is not solved, it takes times new roman by default. If i Use  tag it takes Arial, but does not respect  "font size constant on rotation"

```
<html>
<style type="text/css"> .textprop { font-face: Arial; font-size: 32px;} </style>
<head></head>

<body class="textprop">
    <font face="Arial" size="32px">
        <a href="mailto:subject= Deforestation Position Paper&attachment=Deforestation Position Paper.doc"> Email this page</a><br/>
        <b><i>Responsible Sourcing Guidelines</i></b><br/>
    </font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't know if it solves the problem, but the 'style' tag belongs in the 'head' tag.

Comment: Unfortunately you moved that to before head tag starts. I resolved it by using font-family instead of font-face in the style tag

Answer (score 0):

2 things you need to do. As ChristianK said, you should move your "style" tag in "head", then in your "style", add **-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;** and that should do the trick.